# How to build-in array sub-function in my setAttribute function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written a function that automatically inserts an attribute (i.e. a per case adapted onclick function) in input elements. It also makes a few exceptions. It looks like this, somewhat simplified for clarity reasons:

```
function insertAttribute() {
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var allInputsCount = allInputs.length;
var thatInput = null;
for (i = 0; i < allInputsCount; i++) {
    thatInput = allInputs[i];
    var highlightFunction = "highlightItem('"+thatInput.name+"-row','"+thatInput.name+"-button')";
    if ((thatInput.name != "A") && (thatInput.name != "B") && (thatInput.name != "C"))
        thatInput.setAttribute("onclick",highlightFunction);
    }
}
```

The problem is, there are some 20 exceptions. I could expand the `if` line, but I would rather do it with an array. But how do I do that? I googled `how to use array in javascript function`, and the (two top) results suggest I should do it like this:

```
function insertAttribute() {
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var allInputsCount = allInputs.length;
var thatInput = null;
for (i = 0; i < allInputsCount; i++) {
    thatInput = allInputs[i];
    var highlightFunction = "highlightItem('"+thatInput.name+"-row','"+thatInput.name+"-button')";
    var exceptedArray = ["A","B","C"];
    if (thatInput.name != exceptedArray)
        thatInput.setAttribute("onclick",highlightFunction);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work -- the attribute is still inserted in the exceptions. How should it be done? I would need a vanilla script solution. I'll be happy with a good tutorial, too. As you might have guessed, this is the first time I'm using such an array sub-function.

Comment: you can try `exceptedArray.indexOf(thatInput.name)==-1`, see more functions in [MDN Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Your solution worked fine for the time being, for which I am still grateful, but not when I tested it in IE8. See the below post for the details.

Comment: yep, it depends from js version in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution offered in the comment, `exceptedArray.indexOf(thatInput.name)==-1` worked in most browsers, but not in IE8. Its script debugger said that it did not support `indexOf`. It does in other contexts, but apparently not in this context.

In the meantime, I learned how to make a script loop through an array myself. And this works in all browsers:

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var allInputsCount = allInputs.length;
var thatInput = null;
for (var i=0; i<allInputsCount; i++) {
    thatInput = allInputs[i];
    var highlightFunction = "highlightItem('"+thatInput.name+"-row','"+thatInput.name+"-button')";
    var exceptedNamesArray = ["A","B","C","A4dTInput","A4eTInput"];
    var excNamesArrayCount = exceptedNamesArray.length;
    var excName = null;
    for (var j=0; j<excNamesArrayCount; j++) {
        excName = exceptedNamesArray[j];
        if (thatInput.name != excName)
        thatInput.setAttribute("onclick",highlightFunction);
    }
}
```